# Get arguments from an argument translated as a function

Tags: javascript, arguments

I have a function like this:

```
function MyFunction(argument) {
   argument()
}
```

Is there a way to change argument function's arguments?
Example:

```
MyFunction(function(e) { // e is argument function's argument
  // I want to change e using MyFunction function
})
```

Like...

```
function MyFunction(argument) {
   argument.arguments = "new value"
   // but it returns null...
}
```

Comment: If you're calling it the first way, wouldn't you just supply the arguments when you call `argument`? (`argument(arg1,arg2 ...)`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use bind

Something like:
argument.bind(this, arg1, arg2, arg3, ..., argn)()

Here you can read full documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

```js
//function to call
var logger = function(text){console.log(text)}

logger("hello world");

// You want to overwrite the param with a new one
logger.bind(this, "overwritten parameter")("hello world");
```

Comment: Can I have an example? I don't really understand

Comment: I have adited the comment so you can check how it works.

Comment: Ok, I think my question was a bit hard and not very well explained...
So, I'm gonna explain all of it... I have a function that, when someone sends a message on a game, it does something. And if the user does something like:
`someoneSentMessage(function(e) {
   console.log(e)
})`
I want to change the argument by another one (here, by the message sent)
And, I can't know the argument, the name will be chose by the one that use the function.